# Views Load More: Showing X number of item initially

Tags: views, ajax, javascript

I have a view which shows 6 items per page using Views Load More (Ajax). However what I would like to do is, on the very first page I would like to show 6 items and when clicked on Load More button it should show 3 items and so on. Is it possible?

Comment: that would be a nice feature, can't say I've come across anything that would let you do that though. If there's nothing out there already you could always write a custom pager plugin

Answer (score 1):

Well you could use this workaround.

Have a view with the initial 3 (#1-3). Then add another view below it with an offset of 3, so it shows #4-6. Thus, it will load 3 rows at a time.

You could just show the views back to back on the page or you could use the Insert View module, and have it load the #1-3 view at the header of the 2nd view.